# Pandas add column to df based on values in a second df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate dataframes `df1` and `df2`, both dataframes contain an `id` column which links rows between them. `df2` has a `group` column that `df1` does not contain. What I would like to do is go through each `id` in `df1` and check to see if it is in `df2` then if it is to take the `group` column value and put it in `df1` under a new column of the same name. Would it be easiest to write a function to loop through or is there a pandas trick I could utilize here?

Comment: You may be looking for [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Eg. `pandas.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['id'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'],
                    [2, 'b'],
                    [3, 'c']], columns=['id', 'attr'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 'd'],
                    [3, 'e'],
                    [4, 'f']], columns=['id', 'group'])

df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can merge the two dataframes in one by joining them on the id column and then keep only the columns that you need:

```
df1 = merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='id')
df1.drop('unwanted_column',1)
```